# Cómo mostrar h2 y h3 en tabla de contenido javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

En este código puedo mostrar una tabla de contenido de `h2` y `h3`. El problema es que solo me muestra cuando los `h2` y `h3` están presentes, pero cuando hay solo `h3` en el texto, no me muestra la tabla de contenido. ¿Cómo hago que me aparezca cuando tenga varios `h3`?

Aquí se puede ver funcionando cuando hay `h2` y `h3`:

```js
!function(e) { 
  e; 
  if ($('body.single').length) {

    //Plantillas para la tabla
    var tmplwrap = "<div id='tabla-contenido'>\n<p class='titulo'>Tabla de Contenido</p>\n{contenido}</div>";
    var tmpllink = "<p {clase}><i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i> <a href={link}>{texto}</a></p>\n";
    var cadena = "";

    //Preparamos el segundo nivel para que tenga una clase
    $('article h2').siblings('h3').addClass('n2');

    //Bucle, recorremos elementos para construir la tabla
    $('article h2, article h3').each(function(index, element) {
      clase = $(this).hasClass('n2') ? 'class="n2"' : '';
      texto = $(this).text();
      enlace_id = texto.replace(/\d-\s|\?|¿/g, '');
      enlace_id = enlace_id.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
      $(this).attr('id', enlace_id);

      //Agregamos en una variable cadena
      cadena += tmpllink.replace('{link}', "'#" + enlace_id + "'");
      cadena = cadena.replace('{texto}', texto);
      cadena = cadena.replace('{clase}', clase);
    });
    //Ejemplo de link adicional, descomentar

    //$('div.rel_posts h3').attr('id','relacionados');
    //cadena +="<p><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <a href='#relacionados'>- Artículos relacionados</a></p>\n";
    cadena = tmplwrap.replace('{contenido}', cadena);

    //Finalmente insertamos la cadena antes del primer elemento
    $(cadena).insertBefore($('.entry-content h2').first());
  }
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="single">

  <article class="entry-content">
    <h2>Sección 1</h2>
    <h3>Subsección 1.1</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h2>Sección 2</h2>
    <h3>Subsección 2.1</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h3>Subsección 2.2</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
  </article>

</body>
```

Pero cuando sólo hay `h3`, falla y no se muestra la tabla de contenido:

```js
!function(e) { 
  e; 
  if ($('body.single').length) {

    //Plantillas para la tabla
    var tmplwrap = "<div id='tabla-contenido'>\n<p class='titulo'>Tabla de Contenido</p>\n{contenido}</div>";
    var tmpllink = "<p {clase}><i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i> <a href={link}>{texto}</a></p>\n";
    var cadena = "";

    //Preparamos el segundo nivel para que tenga una clase
    $('article h2').siblings('h3').addClass('n2');

    //Bucle, recorremos elementos para construir la tabla
    $('article h2, article h3').each(function(index, element) {
      clase = $(this).hasClass('n2') ? 'class="n2"' : '';
      texto = $(this).text();
      enlace_id = texto.replace(/\d-\s|\?|¿/g, '');
      enlace_id = enlace_id.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
      $(this).attr('id', enlace_id);

      //Agregamos en una variable cadena
      cadena += tmpllink.replace('{link}', "'#" + enlace_id + "'");
      cadena = cadena.replace('{texto}', texto);
      cadena = cadena.replace('{clase}', clase);
    });
    //Ejemplo de link adicional, descomentar

    //$('div.rel_posts h3').attr('id','relacionados');
    //cadena +="<p><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <a href='#relacionados'>- Artículos relacionados</a></p>\n";
    cadena = tmplwrap.replace('{contenido}', cadena);

    //Finalmente insertamos la cadena antes del primer elemento
    $(cadena).insertBefore($('.entry-content h2').first());
  }
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="single">

  <article class="entry-content">
    <h3>Sección 1</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h3>Sección 2</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h3>Sección 3</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
  </article>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente el código funciona sin problemas cuando sólo hay `h3`, no contiene ningún error y la tabla de contenidos se genera correctamente. Entonces, ¿por qué no se muestra correctamente? Porque a la hora de insertar la cadena antes del primer elemento, indicas que el primer elemento debe ser un `h2`:

```
$(cadena).insertBefore($('.entry-content h2').first());
```

Si no hay ningún `h2` en el artículo, entonces no se va a insertar nada, porque el sitio indicado para la inserción no existe.

Una solución sería decir que la tabla de contenido se inserte como primer elemento del artículo (sin comprobar el tipo del primer elemento ya existente). Para eso puedes usar [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$(".entry-content").prepend(cadena);
```

Y aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
!function(e) { 
  e; 
  if ($('body.single').length) {

    //Plantillas para la tabla
    var tmplwrap = "<div id='tabla-contenido'>\n<p class='titulo'>Tabla de Contenido</p>\n{contenido}</div>";
    var tmpllink = "<p {clase}><i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i> <a href={link}>{texto}</a></p>\n";
    var cadena = "";

    //Preparamos el segundo nivel para que tenga una clase
    $('article h2').siblings('h3').addClass('n2');

    //Bucle, recorremos elementos para construir la tabla
    $('article h2, article h3').each(function(index, element) {
      clase = $(this).hasClass('n2') ? 'class="n2"' : '';
      texto = $(this).text();
      enlace_id = texto.replace(/\d-\s|\?|¿/g, '');
      enlace_id = enlace_id.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
      $(this).attr('id', enlace_id);

      //Agregamos en una variable cadena
      cadena += tmpllink.replace('{link}', "'#" + enlace_id + "'");
      cadena = cadena.replace('{texto}', texto);
      cadena = cadena.replace('{clase}', clase);
    });
    //Ejemplo de link adicional, descomentar

    //$('div.rel_posts h3').attr('id','relacionados');
    //cadena +="<p><i class='fa fa-link'></i> <a href='#relacionados'>- Artículos relacionados</a></p>\n";
    cadena = tmplwrap.replace('{contenido}', cadena);

    //Finalmente insertamos la cadena antes del primer elemento
    $(".entry-content").prepend(cadena);
  }
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="single">

  <article class="entry-content">
    <h3>Sección 1</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h3>Sección 2</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h3>Sección 3</h3>
    <p>Texto</p>
  </article>

</body>
```